# Windows Form App (.NET Framework) CRUD Project, changes successfully saves into DataGridView, but not the actual Database Table

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, crud

This is my first time using C# and SQL. I've managed to get the datagridview to work, be it insert, update or delete. However, all the changes that is reflected in the datagridview is NOT updating in the SQL Table (When I open the database and click "Show Table Data", the Insert, Update and Delete changes are not reflected there.)

Please Help! All the videos I've searched up only shows their datagridview changes being reflected, but doesn't show if their SQL Table is actually updated.

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CRUDProj
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        displaydata();

        button3.Visible = false;

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        chk.HeaderText = "Select";
        chk.ValueType = typeof(bool);
        chk.Name = "chkbox";
        infoDataGridView.Columns.Insert(0, chk);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cRUDDBDataSet.Info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.infoTableAdapter.Fill(this.cRUDDBDataSet.Info);
        

    }

    private void infoBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.infoBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.cRUDDBDataSet);

    }

    private void displaydata()
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRUDProj.Properties.Settings.CRUDDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "select * from [dbo].[Info]";
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
        sdr.Fill(dt);
        infoDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        sqlconn.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRUDProj.Properties.Settings.CRUDDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "insert into [dbo].[Info] values (@Id, @FullName, @NRIC, @Phone, @Temperature, @LocationLevel, @Date)";
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", iDTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", fullNameTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", nRICTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phoneTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Temperature", temperatureTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationLevel", locationLevelTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Inserted");
        displaydata();
        sqlconn.Close();
    }

    public string message = string.Empty;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in infoDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            bool issellected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["chkbox"].Value);
            if (issellected)
            {
                message = Environment.NewLine;
                message = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        label1.Text = message;

        label1.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button4.Enabled = false;
        button5.Enabled = false;


    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRUDProj.Properties.Settings.CRUDDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "update [dbo].[Info] set Id=@Id, FullName=@FullName, NRIC=@NRIC, Phone=@Phone, Temperature=@Temperature, LocationLevel=@LocationLevel, Date=@Date where Id=@Id";
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id" ,label1.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", fullNameTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", nRICTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phoneTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Temperature", temperatureTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationLevel", locationLevelTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTextBox.Text);
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        infoTableAdapter.Update(cRUDDBDataSet.Info);
        sqlconn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully! ");
        displaydata();
        button3.Visible = false;
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button4.Enabled = true;
        button5.Enabled = true;

        DataRowView drv = infoDataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        DataRow[] rowsToUpdate = new DataRow[] { drv.Row };

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.Info", sqlconn);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.Update(rowsToUpdate);

        this.infoTableAdapter.Update(this.cRUDDBDataSet.Info);


    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRUDProj.Properties.Settings.CRUDDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        List<String> empselect = new List<String>();
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i<= infoDataGridView.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            row = infoDataGridView.Rows[i];
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells [0].Value)==true)
            {
                string id = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                empselect.Add(id);
            }
            sqlconn.Open();
            foreach (string s in empselect)
            {
                SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("delete from [dbo].[Info] where Id = ' " + s + " ' ", sqlconn);
                sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully! ");
        displaydata();

    }

    private void iDTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iDTextBox.Clear();
        fullNameTextBox.Clear();
        nRICTextBox.Clear();
        phoneTextBox.Clear();
        temperatureTextBox.Clear();
        locationLevelTextBox.Clear();
        dateTextBox.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @JayV No, no error messages. Everything is working, just that the updates reflected in the dataGridView is not appearing in the actual DB Table

Comment: Then the only thing you can do is debug and step through your code and see whats what during the database operations.

Comment: I could be mistaken; however, I would think you would have problems when calling the `button1_Click` “Insert” event. Inside the button1 click event code, it is calling the `displaydata` method “BEFORE” the connection is closed. I would think this would cause problems since the `displaydata` method “opens” a new connection. Have you stepped through the code to make sure the query is executed fully? It is recommended that you use “Using” statements for the connection and commands.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your DGV to Database this will help you to perform crud operations easily.

### This is a sample code on DGV to perform some actions may it will help you. but make sure that you bind your DGV to the database table.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        _id = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
        string _name = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string _lname = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string _sex = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string _age = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["delete"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if(groupBox1.Visible==true)
            {
                groupBox1.Visible = false;
            }
            _id = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to delete?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result.Equals(DialogResult.OK) && service.deleterecord(_id, _name, _lname, _age, _sex))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("deleted record");
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                
                MessageBox.Show("not deleted");
            }
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["edit"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
            firstname.Text = _name;
            lastname.Text = _lname;
            gender.Text = _sex;
            age.Text = _age;
        }
    }
private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string _fname = firstname.Text;
        string _lname = lastname.Text;
        string _age = age.Text;
        string _sex = gender.Text;
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_fname) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_lname) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_age) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_sex) || gender.Equals(null))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the empty fields");
            }
            else
            {
                if (Updatedata("Update Query"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
                    //this.recordTableAdapter.Fill(this.task2DataSet.record);
                    groupBox1.Visible = false;
                    this.Size = new Size(595, 258);
                    this.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to update");
                }

            }
           
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```